# Merge binary variables into grouping variables by the start of the name in R

Tags: r, merge, grouping, r-caret, dummy-variable

I have a dataset like **original** with numeric (NP) and binary (all the rest) variables (my dataset is much larger and includes way more numeric and dummies):

```
NP <- c(4,6,18,1,3,12,8)
iso_mode_USA <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
iso_mode_CHN <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
iso_mode_COL <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
exp_sector_4 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
exp_sector_5 <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
exp_sector_7 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
original <- data.frame(NP, iso_mode_USA, iso_mode_CHN, iso_mode_COL, exp_sector_4, exp_sector_5, exp_sector_7)
```

I want to **merge the binary** variables **by the start of name** (e.g. all "iso_mode_" together, all "exp_sector_" together, and so on with the rest of variables I have in my dataset not presented here).
In the **new variables** generated I want to input the **value** that is at the **end of the colname() of the original variable**.

So the **new** dataset looks like:

```
NP <- c(4,6,18,1,3,12,8)
iso_mode <- c('USA', 'CHN', 'CHN', 'COL', 'COL', 'USA', 'USA')
exp_sector <- c('5', '4', '4', '7', '4', '7', '7')
new <- data.frame(NP,iso_mode, exp_sector)
```

I have tried with the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372384/r-merge-several-dummy-variable-columns-into-1). However it does not make the trick to select the dummies by names (I have around 1700 dummies in my dataset belonging to only around 20 groups)

Any solution for dplyr() environment?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring the data in long format, keep only rows with value 1, split the column names into two columns and arrange the data back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

original %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -NP) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  extract(name, c('col', 'val'), '(\\w+_\\w+)_(\\w+)') %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = val)

#     NP iso_mode exp_sector
#  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     
#1     4 USA      5         
#2     6 CHN      4         
#3    18 CHN      5         
#4     1 COL      7         
#5     3 COL      4         
#6    12 USA      7         
#7     8 USA      7
```

Comment: Thank you! I have dplyr and tidyr in my library. However, your 4th line does not run in my computer (extract().....) because of the following error: Error in extract(., name, c("col", "val"), "(\\w+_\\w+)_(\\w+)") : 
  Neither texreg nor broom supports models of class tbl_df.

Comment: You are using `extract` from some different library. Use the code with `tidyr::extract`

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` possibility could be:

```
original %>%
 transmute(NP,
           iso_mode = pmap(across(starts_with("iso")), ~ sub(".*\\_", "", names(which(c(...) == 1)))),
           exp_sector = pmap(across(starts_with("exp")), ~ sub(".*\\_", "", names(which(c(...) == 1)))))

  NP iso_mode exp_sector
1  4      USA          5
2  6      CHN          4
3 18      CHN          5
4  1      COL          7
5  3      COL          4
6 12      USA          7
7  8      USA          7
```