# Merge Several Dummy Variable Columns by name

Tags: r, data-manipulation

my question is exactly as [follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372384/r-merge-several-dummy-variable-columns-into-1)

```
library(caret)
data(cars)
head(cars)
colnames(cars)
```

Expected Answer

```
cars$type <- names(cars[14:18])[max.col(cars[14:18])]
```

but using the name of the columns such as below which is not working. how to get around with this? many thanks in advance.

```
cars$type <- cars[c("convertible", "coupe", "hatchback", "sedan", "wagon" )][apply(cars[c("convertible", "coupe", "hatchback", "sedan", "wagon" )], 1, match, x = 1)]
```

head(cars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset dataframe by name in the similar fashion -

```
cols <- c("convertible", "coupe", "hatchback", "sedan", "wagon" )
cars$type <- cols[max.col(cars[cols])]
```

To check the output -

```
identical(cols[max.col(cars[cols])] , names(cars[14:18])[max.col(cars[14:18])])
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to specify the `ties.method` or else it can choose `"random"` as default and this could change the outcome in each run where there are multiple `max` values per row

```
cols <- c("convertible", "coupe", "hatchback", "sedan", "wagon" )
cars$type <- cols[max.col(cars[cols], "first")]
```